# Is there a free (LGPL compatible) Grid plugin for jQuery that has similiar capabilities to the Ext-JS Grid?

Tags: jquery, user-interface, extjs, grid

One of the most appealing features of Ext-JS is the [Grid control](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/grid/array-grid.html) in my opinion. I was searching for something free that does something close and have set my hopes on jQuery.

I haven't found a jQuery (or other LGPL compatible) Table / Grid plugin that allows to:

- Reorder columns by dragging
- Resize columns by dragging
- Add or Remove columns on the fly
- Have a default good looking UI (subjective, but Ext-JS look I think is a concensus)

In addition to the rest most grid controls have (Sort, Paging etc)

**Is there a free (LGPL) jQuery plugin that does the above?**

Comment: Is the reason to not use the ExtJS grid because of the licensing ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may take a look at [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.net/demophp.aspx) which is commercial (the column reordering/resizing demo is in the Functionality/Misc menu).

Alternatives:

- [Flexgrid](http://flexigrid.info/)
- [Datatables](http://www.datatables.net/index)
- [Ingrid](http://reconstrukt.com/ingrid/)
- [jqGridView](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jqGridView)
- [SlickGrid](http://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/)

Comment: Looks great, though I'm looking for something free and not server side bound. I'll update the question.

Comment: Flexgrid looks great, though a bit quaky, but looks very close to Ext-JS, thanks